# Change a state value without a full reload in Next.js 14

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js13, react-typescript

Using a modal, I am prompting a user to input they OpenAI key and save it to localStorage. If it's not empty, the dialog closes. However, if they try to edit it without reloading the page it will display an not updated, previous value. How to make it display the current value? router.refresh() does not work.

Also, I want to check the validity of the key. I'm thinking that it would just be a simple call to an API route, which calls the OpenAI API. How should I go about this? Would I need to use Bcrypt to make such a call from this client component? (it passes the api key to my api)

```
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogFooter,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui/dialog';
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';
import { Label } from '@/components/ui/label';
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { FormEvent, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Spinner from './ui/spinner';

export default function ApiKeyDialog() {
  const [apiKey, setApiKey] = useState('');
  const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  const closeDialog = useCallback(() => {
    setOpen(false);
  }, [setOpen]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      setApiKey(
        localStorage.getItem('openai_api_key') == null ||
          localStorage.getItem('openai_api_key') == ''
          ? ''
          : (localStorage.getItem('openai_api_key') as string)
      );
      setOpen(apiKey == '' ? true : false);
    }
  }, [apiKey]);

  //TODO: add trycatch blocks
  async function handleSubmit(e: FormEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
    localStorage.setItem('openai_api_key', input);
    closeDialog();
  }

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
      <DialogTrigger asChild>
        <Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)} variant='outline'>
          Edit API Key
        </Button>
      </DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent className='sm:max-w-[425px]'>
        <form>
          <DialogHeader>
            <DialogTitle>Edit API Key</DialogTitle>
            <DialogDescription>
              Make changes to your OPENAI key here.
            </DialogDescription>
          </DialogHeader>
          <div className='grid gap-4 py-4'>
            <div className='grid grid-cols-4 items-center gap-4'>
              <Label htmlFor='apikey' className='text-right'>
                API Key:
              </Label>
              <Input
                onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
                id='apikey'
                defaultValue={apiKey}
                placeholder='key'
                className='col-span-3'
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <DialogFooter>
            <Button type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>
              Save changes
              {loading ? <Spinner /> : null}
            </Button>
          </DialogFooter>
        </form>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```